# Client side validation not working in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

The client-side validation in ASP.Net Core is not working. I have the following code:

```html
@model VeoScheduling.Models.SignInModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SignIn";
}
<div class="login">
    <h2>Sign In</h2>
    <div>
        <form method="post" asp-action="SignIn">

            <input type="hidden" asp-for="RedirectUrl" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="email"
                       data-bind="value: email" asp-for="Email"
                       class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"
                       class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="password" asp-for="Password"
                       data-bind="value: password"
                       class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Account</label>
                <select name="accountSelected" style="margin:5px;width:200px"
                        data-bind='options: availableAccounts, optionsText: "value", optionsValue: "key", value: selectedAccount,event:{change: accountSelected()}'></select>
            </div>
            <br />

            @if (Model.Error != "" || Model.Error != null)
            {
                <p style="color:red">@Html.Raw(Model.Error)</p>
            }

        </form>
    </div>

</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        var vModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))
    </script>

    <script src="~/js/signIn.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

I have also added javascript validation files and I can see they are being loaded when I run but still client-side validation is not working.

[image]

I have applied required attribute for both email and password filed. But client-side validation is still not working.

```html
 public class SignInModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Email is required")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Password is required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Forgot Password")]
        public bool ForgotPassword { get; set; }

        public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }

        public string Error { get; set; }
    }
```

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
    self.vm = new viewModel(self.vModel);
    ko.applyBindings(self.vm);
});
```

Below is the js code.

```html
var viewModel = function (model) {
    var self = this;

    //properties
    self.email = ko.observable('');
    self.password = ko.observable('');
    self.redirectUrl = model.redirectUrl;

    self.availableAccounts = ko.observableArray(model.availableAccounts);
    self.selectedAccount = ko.observable(null);

    //events
    self.signOn = function () {

        var payloadData = {
            'email': self.email(),
            'password': self.password(),
            'accountSelected': self.selectedAccount()
        };

        var url = window.location.origin + '/account/SignIn';

        CallService("Post", url, payloadData)
            .done(function (data) {

                var url = window.location.origin + self.redirectUrl;

                window.location.replace(url);
            });

    };
    self.accountSelected = function (e, d) {
        //alert(self.selectedStack());
    };

    //methods
    self.forgotPassword = ko.observable(false);

    self.resetPassword = function () {


        $('#loader').show();

        var payloadData = {
            'email': self.email()
        };

        var url = window.location.origin + '/API/resetPassword'

        $.post(url, payloadData)
            .always(function () {
                $('#loader').hide();
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('resetPassword(): error' + xhr.responseText);
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                alert("reset email sent.");
            });

    };


    //ajax
    self.getUsersAccounts = function () {

        if (self.email() === "")
            return;

        var payloadData = {
            'email': self.email()
        };

        var url = window.location.origin + '/API/GetAccountsByEmail';

        CallService("GET", url, payloadData)
            .done(function (data) {

                self.availableAccounts.removeAll();
                self.availableAccounts(data);


            });

    };


    //computed
    self.userChanged = ko.computed(function () {
        var userID = self.email();
        //alert(userID);
        //console.log(userID);
        self.getUsersAccounts();
    });

    self.forgotChecked = ko.computed(function () {
        var checked = self.forgotPassword();
        var email = self.email();
        if (checked) {
            if (email === '') {
                alert("Please fill in email to reset password");
                self.forgotPassword(false);
            }
            else {
                alert("An email link will be sent to your email address.");
                self.resetPassword();
                self.forgotPassword(false);

            }
        }

    });

    //init
    if (model.availableAccounts.length === 1) {
        self.selectedAccount(model.availableAccounts[0].key);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    self.vm = new viewModel(self.vModel);
    ko.applyBindings(self.vm);
});
```

Comment: seems like path should be something like "~/js/jquery.validate.min.js" for the script src.  (just as you have for your signin script)

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
<form id="someform">
......
</form>

<script>
.....
if ($("#someform").valid()) 
{
  //ajax codes
}
else {
        return false;
     }
</script>
```

also you could try:

```
var somevalue = document.getElementById("someId").value;
if (somevalue == null || somevalue == '') 
{
    $('#somespanId').html("*required");
    return false;
}
```